# Linux driver: MFD over PCI

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, pci

I am writing a driver for a PCI device. The device is a custom development FPGA based device. The FPGA has multiple "devices" on board. I want my driver to create the proper interfaces for those devices.

A certain part of the device will use our own "part". But for I2C busses, I would like to use the already available opencores driver. In the past I had to add the I2C compatible property to the correct "device" in my DTS under my FPGA device (FPGA to CPU was SPI).

Now this has to go over PCI.
The kernel uses my FPGA driver and probes, also created the "own part" as chardev. the I2C opencores drivers `->probe()` functions seems not to be called when I create a MFD-cell with the correct compatible property. The cell is added, but never probed.

I use Linux kernel v4.9 on a 64-bit ARM based CPU.

```c
struct x_my_dev {
    struct list_head        x_my_dev;
    struct mfd_cell         *mfd_cell;
    struct device_node      *of_node;
    struct property         *compat_prop;
    struct resource         *irq_resource;
    struct platform_devive      *pdev;
};

...

struct x_my_dev *my_dev;

...
ret = mfd_add_devices(priv->dev, PLATFORM_DEVID_NONE,
            my_dev->mfd_cell, 1, NULL, irq_base, NULL)

if (ret) {
    dev_err(priv->dev, "Failed to add mfd cell\n");
    goto err_mfd_add;
}

...
```

- Already checked if the opencores driver is available in the kernel
- The kernel `/sys/class/my_fpga/device/I2C_bus/` has only 'driver_override', 'modalias', 'power', 'subsystem' and 'uevent'. Nothing that shows what drivers needs to be used.

Comment: First of all, your kernel version is quite old (start with v6.1). Second, the Linux kernel has an FPGA manager framework. Your driver should use it. Or wait for a better solution specifically for FPGA connected to the PCIe bus.